# Windows 8 upgrade to windows 8.1 RTM fails with error code 0x101 - 0x2000C

Tags: windows-8, installation, upgrade, windows-8.1

I have a MSDN Subscription and downloaded Windows 8.1 RTM today.

It fails to install.

After mounting the ISO and installing (with a Windows 8.1 Pro product code), selecting "Keep my apps and settings", it copies  all installation files, restarts and then bluescreens at around 50%, then rolls back to the previous version.

System has 64 GB Memory, Supermicro, Xeon E5-1650, Intel SSD, runs Hyper-V, Windows 8 Pro.

What may be causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is there an error message displayed when it blue screens and what is it doing just before it blue screens (if it actually tells you what it is doing at that point)?

Comment: As I said, it was installing, at around 50%, then a bluescreen appeared for a short while,displaying the error message in the header, then restarted

Comment: upload the dmp file of the BSOD

Comment: The strange this is that no new DMP files are found (only old ones from a few months back)

Comment: check if you have enough disk space available. the 4gb that microsoft tells you need is a lie. If you are on the edge (let's say you have 8 free, i recommend to go with more than 10gb)

Comment: I have 250 GB free space so that is not a problem.

Comment: I installed a newer version of my display driver, but in the end waited with the update until I could upgrade through the store. Then the upgrade proceeded with no pain.

Comment: ^ You should make this as an answer.

Comment: I would understand why it would be due to a driver update. The compatibility is bad enough with windows 8 itself... it then gets even worse still when upgrading to 8.1 even though it isn't really a bog standard OS reinstall/Update...

Answer (score 0):

Disable Windows Firewall and then try to install Windows 8.1. 
Details are here: [Windows Firewall from start to finish](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114140552/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-8/windows-firewall-from-start-to-finish).

OR

Boot the computer in Clean Boot and try to install Windows 8.1: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1_pr-windows_install/error-0x101-0x2000c/26d95130-85fd-4045-9127-db27cab735d4)